# How to airdrop tokens successfully

Tags: remix, metamask, airdrop

[image]

I have the script for airdropping tokens, all I need is to know what and how to input these value on the drop section of remix script:token,recipient,values.

Assuming I want to send to 5 addresses, please respond with a sample that we can copy and paste into the fields.

[image: help]

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to enter in your contract argument fields.

token field: "Address of the token contract"
recipients field: ["address1", "address2", "address3", "address4, address5"]
values field: [1,2,3,4,5]

I'm updating my answer after you've provided code. 
your code is insecure. Below I've made you a simple airdrop contract, I'm sure you spot the differences.

```
    contract AirDrop is Owned {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    uint8   public constant DECIMALS = 18;
    uint256 public constant DECIMALFACTOR = 10 ** uint256(DECIMALS);
    uint256 public AIRDROP_SUPPLY = 10000000 * uint256(DECIMALFACTOR);
    uint256 public TOTAL_SUPPLY = 1000000000000 * uint256(DECIMALFACTOR);
    uint256 public claimedTokens = 0;

    AirdropToken public airdropToken;

    mapping (address => bool) public airdropReceivers;

    event AirDropped (
        address[] _recipients, 
        uint256 _amount, 
        uint256 claimedTokens);

    constructor() public {
        airdropToken = new AirdropToken(this);
    }

    function airDrop(address[] _recipients, uint256 _amount) external onlyOwner {
        require(_amount > 0);
        uint256 airdropped;
        uint256 amount = _amount * uint256(DECIMALFACTOR);
        for (uint256 index = 0; index < _recipients.length; index++) {
            if (!airdropReceivers[_recipients[index]]) {
                airdropReceivers[_recipients[index]] = true;
                airdropToken.transfer(_recipients[index], amount);
                airdropped = airdropped.add(amount);
            }
        }
    AIRDROP_SUPPLY = AIRDROP_SUPPLY.sub(airdropped);
    TOTAL_SUPPLY = TOTAL_SUPPLY.sub(airdropped);
    claimedTokens = claimedTokens.add(airdropped);
    emit AirDropped(_recipients, _amount, claimedTokens);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The value field, does it represent how many tokens that will be sent to each address? e.g [1,2,3,4,5] could mean, 100,200,200,300,400 tokens to each address?

Comment: This is what i got after trying it as i specified above,

Comment: It shows as if i created a contract on etherscan instead of showing me that i sent out tokens

Comment: how do ispecify the amount of tokes to go to each address?

Comment: Without knowing the code, I highly believe that the value field represents how many tokens will be sent to each address, here you can place the amount you want to send, I just showed you a template of how to do it properly. If it is not working, then show the code of the script.

Comment: This is the script I used,please let me know if it is correct.

Comment: contract ERC20 {
  function transfer(address _recipient, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
}
 
contract Airdrop {
  function drop(ERC20 token, address[] recipients, uint256[] values) public {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
      token.transfer(recipients[i], values[i]);
    }
  }
}

Comment: Thank you,I have seen the airdrop contract you have created.I appreciate.So I should continue as usual,load this new airdrop script on remix and include the values and recipients and the contract will run,right?

Comment: Yes, however, you have to change the script to fit your needs, I made you an example of how a simple airdrop might look like but with whitelisting etc. So if you don't need this you can just take what you need.

Answer (score 1):

That contract is insecure. Anyone can call it, and airdrop all the tokens to themselves. Do not send any tokens to it unless you're OK with losing them.

Comment: Thank you James, Please how can i get a secure contract.....to airdrop the tokens.... any suggestions?

Comment: The simplest way would be to add `require(msg.sender == 0xyouraddress);`. Or you could reuse the `Ownable` mixin from Zeppelin, and make the function `onlyOwner`, which amounts to the same thing.

Comment: check my edited answer for an example of a airdrop contract.

Answer (score 0):

Some days ago  I can't do  exactly that you want  from **Remix**: pass array to function params.  But  I have can do this  with https://www.myetherwallet.com/  (MEW)

1. Go to the Contract page (https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts )
2. In Contract Address field point to your deployed contract
3. In ABI/JSON Interface field insert ABI, you can take it from remix (Compile page-Details button-ABI section)
4. Push Access button
5. Chois  your  airdrop method  from dropdown box
6. In the field below you will see  to fields  for  your  params And 
   now **!!!!! atention!!!!** put your addresses and amounts
   **without** [ ],   just comma.

Look  like  this.
[image]
Then  connect  to your wallet  and  push write.

In this  example  there is not  airdrop method,   but  there is multiTransfer - it's  same,  you can see here
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x0db720da802ea43ba7e725c868cd6fed2db06a9c#code

Comment: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x0db720da802ea43ba7e725c868cd6fed2db06a9c#code

Comment: I have tried this but i think the problem is the ABI code copied from Remix,i can see the multitransfer option and have actually executed it,it said the transaction was successful,but it failed on etherscan. Am I supposed to get an ABI that is particular for my token or will i just use that of Cryptoindex100(because i noticed that it has the multitransfer it has the multi transfer option.

Comment: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x21de48628fd14e82ba09794db0d5f09b545714e48983e571153342ddd21534d9. I am almost through,pls dont give up on me