# How to Distribute token to multiple address

Tags: tokens

I'm writing a smart contract to distribute the created tokens to multiple address. Looking around on the web I may found what I was looking for but I don't know how to insert the addresses in the field; I tried in different ways but none worked. This is the function to distribute token ( Sorry, I do not know how to insert code into website):

```
function adminClaimAirdropMultiple(address[] _addresses, uint _amount) external {        
    for (uint i = 0; i < _addresses.length; i++)
        doAirdrop(_addresses[i], _amount);
}
```

I tried to insert the addresses in these ways:

```
["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
 "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002",
 "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003"]
```

but no one worked. How can I solve this?

Comment: How are you calling your function? Is it with a wallet or a script?

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img922/7097/XBRBRk.png

Comment: You seems to be using MyEtherWallet, I don't use it very much try this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/48318.

Comment: https://rstormsf.github.io/multisender/#/ there is nice Dapp that works with metamask