# how to implement an airdrop function inside a smart contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20, airdrop

I have a Erc20 token X and an Smart Contract A

Smart Contract A contains 1000 X Tokens.

How can an User get an defined amount of X Tokens from this Smart Contract? (something like an Airdrop)

So Basically a user should call a method like: `getAirdrop()` and then should get 100 X tokens from A's wallet

I tried the following:

```
function getAirdrop(){
    erc20TOken.transferFrom(this, msg.sender, 10000000000000000000);
}
```

... and...

```
function getAirdrop(){
    erc20TOken.increaseApproval(msg.sender, 100000000000000000000);
}
```

... but do not work.

Comment: Might be worth checking out a related [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48290/how-to-airdrop-tokens-successfully), as well as the source code of [Airdropper](https://github.com/bitfwdcommunity/Airdropper) for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, I made this example for you:

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

//Made to Stackexchange question

contract ERC20 {
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)public returns(bool);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner)public view returns(uint balance);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens)public returns(bool success);

}

contract SimpleAirdrop {

      ERC20 public token;

        function SimpleAirdrop(address _tokenAddr) public {
        token = ERC20(_tokenAddr);
}

  function getAirdrop() public {
    token.transfer(msg.sender, 100000000000000000000); //18 decimals token
  }
```

}

Remember, you need send tokens to contract.

You can see this compiling here: https://ethfiddle.com/EIxLLnYFDJ

Answer (score 0):

If the contract A owns the required tokens you can simply use the `transfer` function in the ERC20 token contract.

So something like this (assuming you have a reference `erc20TOken` to the actual token contract):

```
function getAirdrop() public { 
  erc20TOken.transfer(msg.sender, 100); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

But how can you be sure, that user has finalized all tasks to get tokens? I assume tokens should be sent manually by owner (or implemented on backend).
But also interested in answers with more experience.

Comment: That's the baset way, make a multiairdrop contract to a list of address, by the way, theres a couple o dapps that to the same